# List instance with unique id

Tags: list

i have a designer workflow for a list instance.
When i redeploy the list definition and list instance from VS 2010 solution the list is recreated and the association between the workflow and the list is lost.

site requires only one instance of the list so can i create the instance with fix GUID all the time it created ?

please suggest

Answer (score 1):

This is done best through SharePoint feature recievers. You can create and associate lists, you can also ensure a list does not exist.

If you are worried about redeploying from VS 2010 in your dev enviornment,  you can set the configuration to not activate the feature automatically when you deploy via Visual Studio. I would recommend your feature which creates content/taxonomy be seperated from other features such as webparts/pages/dlls to ensure you can automatically refresh custom code in your enviornments.

[Same Question](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/63d9241c-e1d9-4d0b-b73c-07909065ff02/)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is select the List Instance in Solution Explorer, and then change the Deployment Conflict Resolution property (in the Properties window) to None. This way, the list instance won't be overwritten when the feature is activated.